# Subgroups of a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If we have a group $G$ of order $10$, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then Lagrange's theorem states each $H$ may be of order $1, 2, 5$ or $10$. Now we have the trivial subgroup $\lbrace e\rbrace$ of order $1$ and the subgroup of $G$ itself. Clearly both of these contain the identity element ($e$). Do all subgroups of a group contain the identity element?

Comment: Yes. Any subgroup of any group must contain the identity element.

Comment: Part of the definition of a group is that it contains an identity.  A subgroup is a subset that is a group.

Comment: @TimRatigan Ah yes how silly, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, part of the definition of a subgroup is that $e \in H$. Actually there is a deeper reason for this requirement:

We want $H$ to be a group. Then $H$ must have an identity, lets call it $e'$. Now we have in $H$

$$e'e'=e' $$

But this identity must hold in $G$, and multiplying by $e'^{-1} \in G$ we get that
$$e'=e $$

It follows that as long as we ask for $H$ to be a group, with the same operation as in $G$, it's identity must be the identity of $G$.

This is the reason why the definition always asks for $e \in H$.

**P.S.** If $G$ is finite, as long as $H$ is a non-empty subset of $G$ such that for all $x,y \in H$ we also have $xy \in H$, it follows that $H$ must contain $e$.

Comment: Your postscript requires the added assumption that $H$ be nonempty. ;)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Ty, missed that :)

Answer (score -1):

Do all subgroups of a group contain the identity element?
YES!  A subgroup is a subset of a group which is a group in its own right.... do all groups require an identity?  YES!!!

Comment: BUT.... Maybe the identity of $H$ is not the same...

Comment: If I remember right, a subset of a monoid can be a monoid with the inherted structure, but have a different identity...

Comment: TRUE!  But the OP probably is an undergrad preparing for a first course in group theory and "monoid" is a term completely foreign to him/her.  If I recall correctly, semigroups can have no identities, one, several, or everything be an identity.

Comment: By definition monoids have an unique identity. Anyhow, that's not the point, the point I am making is that the simple fact that $H \subset G$, and $H$ requires an identity doesn't necessarily mean that this identity has to be the identity of $G$. For groups it can be proven, but this comes from the fact that every element in $G$ has an inverse.... It is not just $H$ has an identity, $G$ has an identity so the identity of $G$ is in $H$....

Comment: OKay... good point. I see what you are saying now.

Comment: If $e$ and $e'$ are two different identity elements in a semigroup, then $e \cdot e' = ???$